# Get largest value of primary key from DynamoDB table using boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am trying to get a largest value of a primary key (`id` in a particular case) using boto3.

Table structure:

`| id  | name  |
|-----|-------|
| 1   | Bob   |
| 4   | Alice |
| 5   | Eve   |`

where `id` is a primary key (hash key) and there is no sort key (range key).

As a result, I should get 5 (the `id` largest value).

I have looked thought [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.Python.04.html) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37132223/how-to-query-the-greates-value-sortkey-range-dynamodb?noredirect=1&lq=1) but didn't find an answer.

`ScanIndexForward` attribute from `table.scan()` method requires sort key. `table.query()` method requires condition (such as `Key={"name":"Bob"}`).

The `id` value is not autoincrementing (table may have missing `id` values) that is why [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44959930/python-retrieving-max-primary-key-value-from-dynamodb-using-boto3) solution doesn't help.

Question: Is it possible to get largest `id` from a table without sort key? (Of course, I do not want to scan *all* table and find it using python.)

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably not what you want to hear- but you can't do this using table operations directly.

Dynamo gives you a lot of constraints in the name of making a scalable system. And most of these surround the options you have for querying; offering more of a key'd document store then a traditional database [(further discussion about using scan with some, dubious, suggestions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21794945/dynamodb-scan-in-sorted-order).

I suggest you take a look at the way you need to access your data and consider your schema design within the limits of partition/sort/indexes.

For situations like this (e.g. when you need to derive a property from the table), an architectural pattern you can use is:

```
DynamoDB
  -> DynamoDB Streams (shares Create/Update/Delete events)
  -> Lambda checks id against a stored value of 'current max id':
       - if create/update and higher, saves 'current max id' and 'last max id'
       - if delete and equal, replace 'current max id' with 'last max id'
```

In this case you could store the resulting 'view' of maximum id in another table, or a versioned s3 document. (n.b. there's still some limitations, you might need to do a `scan` if the two largest ids are deleted using this implementation).